# "Problem: solved." or "Problem, solved." or "Problem—solved."

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes, colons

How should one correctly achieve the flow of this short sentence through the use of punctuation?

- Problem. Solved.

In my specific example, I'm writing about how to restore creativity lost to the overuse of mobile phones by simply getting rid of your phone, and I have these sentences:

> - Time for drawing and painting on paper: restored.
> - Time for spacing
>     out and coming up with ideas: restored.
> - Need to actually look at
>     things and remember them with your eyes and your own brain: restored.
> - Creativity: boosted.

Comment: Consistency of punctuation and capitalization in a parallel series: priceless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to represent a table with two columns (something like *target* and *result*) with punctuation, and there's not really a "correct" answer, but by far the most common convention is to use a colon. See for example the screen capture from a television commercial from the classic 1997 Mastercard "Priceless" campaign in [this blog post](http://www.cmo.com/articles/2013/8/19/three_lessons_from_m.html), where "real conversation: priceless" is rendered with a colon.

Comment: I think you're saying that I got it right, except that there is no "right." I'm very tempted to mark this as answered but will wait to see if anybody else posts an answer before I do. Thanks!